# JS delegating/extending aleady existing function

Tags: javascript, delegates

**How to add code to the function preserving it's old functionality**

```
SomeFunction = function () {
    someOtherFunction();
    return this.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like that

```
var delegate = functionToBeDelegated;
functionToBeDelegated = function () {

    //
    // Add functionality to the function
    //

    // run the old version of the function in native scope
    return delegate.apply(this, arguments);
};
```